# Audio na mesma página. Play em um para o outro

Tags: áudio

Estou tentando o seguinte:

Criei audio1 e audio2 com base no que aprendi aqui no fórum. Acontece que o resultado não foi o desejado, ou seja, clicando nos dois ouve-se os dois sons. Gostaria que clicando em um (play) o e outro desse pause. Não gostaria de permitir ouvi dos sons ao mesmo tempo. Aqui tem uma exemplo:
 [inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://www.vaticannews.va/pt/oracoes.html)

```
$(function(){
  $("#audio1").on('click', function(){
    var pe = $("#audio2").get(0); 
    if(pe.paused == false)
      pe.pause();
  });
  $("#audio2").on('click', function(){
    var pe = $("#audio1").get(0); 
    if(pe.paused == false)
      pe.pause();
  });
});

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <audio id="audio1" controls>
             <source src="http://w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
        </audio>
        <br />

        <audio id="audio2" controls>
            <source src="http://w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
        </audio>
        <br />
    </body>
</html>
```

Alguém pode ,e ajudar. Obrigado

Comment: Daniel, é exatamente isso. Sucesso para você. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Carlos, utilize o evento **play** no lugar do evento **click**:

```
$(function(){

  $("#audio1").on('play', function(){
    var pe = $("#audio2").get(0);

    if(pe.paused == false)
      pe.pause();
  });

  $("#audio2").on('play', function(){
    var pe = $("#audio1").get(0);

    if(pe.paused == false)
      pe.pause();
  });

});

<html>

    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <audio id="audio1" controls>
             <source src="http://w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
        </audio>

        <br />

        <audio id="audio2" controls>
            <source src="http://w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
        </audio>

        <br />
    </body>

</html>
```